# Unable to install Wine32

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 and trying to install wine via `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging`

Which then tells me

`Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 3.19.0~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`
By using synaptic, I've come to a conclusion that there are no broken packages so, what do?

Comment: How did you enable `winehq-staging` and `wine-staging`?  Are you using the WineHQ repositories?

Comment: I enabled them with `sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/`

Comment: And you did a `sudo apt-get update` afterwards, correct?

Comment: Yes on the site it also tells you to do so.